# MySQL group by with max value

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

Hi I have this table.

```
id  lat     lng     userId
1   12      23      1
2   45      34      2
3   42      34      3
4   33      34      1
5   36      79      2
6   53      98      2
7   23      90      3
8   23      67      1
```

Here we have three users. (user ids 1,2,3). I want to get lateset record (id column max value) of each user.
My excepted output is this

```
userId  lat     lng
1       23      67
2       53      98
3       23      90
```

This query will give me group by option

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    covid.locations
GROUP BY userId;
```

But how do I combine this with `MAX(id)` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
SELECT
*
FROM
covid.locations
where id in (select max(t.id) from covid.locations t group by t.userId)
order by id desc;
```

An example of the above query can be found in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07ce7d/25)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use the following:

```
SELECT
    cl.*
FROM covid.locations cl
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            userid
          , MAX( id ) mid
        FROM covid.locations
        GROUP BY
            userId
    ) g ON cl.userid = g.userid
    AND cl.id = cl.mid
```

Another is to use `row_number() over()`

```
SELECT
    userId
  , lat
  , lng
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM covid.locations
    GROUP BY
        userId
) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

Both will identify the "most recent" row in the source table based in the `id` column of that table. Note that the second query requires MySQL version 8+ as this is when `row_number()` became supported in that database. The first query should run in dbms supporting SQL.